# Should there be a mutex for every setter in a class or making all member variables atomic to be threadsafe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I'm writing a class which has lots of set-able variables.  The requirement is now that class should be thread-safe. So my options as far as I know is to use mutexes or make variables atomic(or both of them). I have several questions concerning this as I 'm not sure how to go about it.

- Should I make all member variables (which range from  int, float, bools to std::map, etc) atomic? and then refrain from using mutexes in their setter and getters unless they have more logics than a simple assignment?
- Should I create separate mutexes for all setters or should I use a single mutex for all operations that are related (for example, add/read/remove users, get_user_count, set_user_count, etc)

Would having both mutex and atomic member variables be a bad idea performance wise, that is, suppose I made my `statusChanged` variable atomic and also it is used in a method that has some logic and thus I use a scoped_lock to make the whole block threadsafe. would that be overkill? would the mutex be enough?

Comment: There is no one right way to do this. It depends on the details of the class and how it's used. You won't get a useful answer without asking a much more specific question. For example, if it's a class that there's typically only one instance of, the solutions might be totally different from what you'd use if it was a class that there would be tens of thousands of instances of.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought we should not have any assumption about how user uses our class. am I wrong in this? Its supposed to be instantiated once, but becasue what I just said(not assuming how a clinet uses your code),  I didnt get specific in this.

Comment: Atomic variables and mutexes are not drop-in replacements for each other. They have different semantics and they are used differently. In order to make an intelligent decision you will have to figure out what kind of multi-threaded semantics are required. If interthread sequencing is complicated, using mutexes will be pretty much the only options. Atomic variables, themselves, do not have as sophisticated sequencing as mutexes. But if atomic sequences is sufficient, they'll have less overhead to deal with. What kind of sequncing you need is something you need to figure out yourself.

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you. How you make a synchronization primitive thread safe, how you make a database thread safe, and how you make a configuration container class thread safe are all completely different. Often, the right answer is just to let the calling code worry about it, since the calling code has more information about how the class is being used.

Comment: It could also be the case that you're approaching the problem incorrectly altogether, and thread safety can be avoided by a different architecture. But it's hard to tell with the little information you give. There is no general rule of thumb.

Comment: You are right. what kind of information do you need me to provide to make it more explicit/clear?

Answer (score 2):

Thread-safe is not a property of a class.  Thread safe is a relational property between two pieces of code and data.

Both the mutex based exclusion strategy and atomic strategy has the problem that they do not compose.  "A" can be thread safe, "B" can be thread safe, and "A+B" can fail to be thread safe,

A simple example of that is an object with one property `x`, and reader/writer locks guarding setter and getter methods.  Doing something as simple as `obj.x = obj.x+2` -- composing a read and a write -- can't work "thread safely"; afterwards, x may not be 2 bigger than before.

If you make `x` atomic and start doing CAS type "atomic" operations, you can get `x+=2` thread safe; but then if you have two fields `x` and `y`, the simple composition `x=y+2` cannot be done thread safely with another thread calculating `y-x`.

---

Basically, mutex guarded accessors, or atomic exposed data, doesn't get you thread safety.  Many reasonable operations won't work reasonably.

You can back away from this model entirely -- go with message queues and immutable shared data etc -- but that may be out of scope.  So if you are stuck with the idea of "thread safe mutable objects", you should do something like this:

```
template<class T>
struct mutex_guarded {
  template<class F>
  auto read(F&& f)const{
    auto l=lock();
    return f(t);
  }
  template<class F>
  auto write(F&& f){
    auto l=lock();
    return f(t);
  }
  mutex_guarded(T tin):t(std::move(tin)){}
  mutex_guarded()=default
private:
  mutable std::mutex m;
  T t;
  auto lock() const { return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m); }
};
```

use looks like:

```
struct data {int x,y;};
mutex_guarded<data> d( {5,3} );
std::cout << d.read([&](auto& d){return d.y-d.x;});
d.write([&](auto& d){++d.y;d.x=d.y+2;});
```

put the `.write` and `.read` lines in different threads, or loop, or whatever, and the `.read` will always print 2.

The object is not thread safe.  Rather, we wrapped it in explicit mutex guarded access.  This can resist attempts to "accidentally" compose it (as the block where you have the lock is obvious) more than needed, while permitting complex "atomic" (indivisible, not std atomic) operations if needed.

(I split read/write, because a shared mutex is a natural next step.  Also it makes const-correct access a tad easier.  To make shared mutex (rw-lock) work, add const and non-const overloads to lock; const returns shared lock, non-const unique.  And, of course, replace mutex with shared mutex.)

Apologies for any typos; written without testing as yet.

```
template<class T>
struct shared_mutex_guarded {
  template<class F>
  auto read(F&& f)const{
    auto l=lock();
    return f(t);
  }
  template<class F>
  auto write(F&& f){
    auto l=lock();
    return f(t);
  }
  shared_mutex_guarded(T tin):t(std::move(tin)){}
  shared_mutex_guarded()=default
private:
  mutable std::shared_mutex m;
  T t;
  auto lock() { return std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>(m); }
  auto lock() const { return std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex>(m); }
};
```

Comment: `std::scoped_lock` would already be sufficient here, right?

Comment: @jhbo prior to guaranteed elision, not as written.  After, yes.

Comment: to be sure, that's starting from C++17 right?